# Bulk import module

Tags: nodes, batch-operations

I've created a custom content type and I need to enter 30 or so records. The type has around 5 fields.

Is there a module that provides a table for me to enter these details? At the moment, I assume I need to enter them one by one, or spend time writing some kind of mySQL script.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) - Import or aggregate data as nodes, users, taxonomy terms or simple database records.
2. [Node import](http://drupal.org/project/node_import) - Node import allows users to import content (node, user, taxonomy) from CSV or TSV files.
3. [Node export](http://drupal.org/project/node_export) - This module allows users to export nodes and then import it into another Drupal installation, or on the same site.
4. [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) - The migrate module provides a flexible framework for migrating content into Drupal from other sources

I am recommend for simple case node import/export using. If importing happen eventually and it's simple, then Feeds. If import make hard data and big count of records, then Migrate.